# How can I make an optical circulator?

Tags: components, optics, passive-components, optical-fibre

I need to a single mode 1550 optical circulator at my lab. I have a varied supply of components, but no circulator. Any idea how I can make one myself? Perhaps using coupler and isolator?

Thanks.

-D

Comment: How is this in any sense related to electrical engineering?

Comment: This is off-topic because it's about optics, not electronics.

Answer (score 1):

If you didn't mind throwing away 1/2 the power you could make one with beam splitters and isolators.  But maybe just buy one from Thor labs.. ~$600.